# The derivative of $-e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x}\cdot 5x^3$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Calculate the derivative of
>
> $$-e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x}\cdot 5x^3$$

Well, we use the product rule. Which is like "the derivative of the first by the second, plus the derivative of the second by the first":

$$(-1\cdot e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x} \cdot \sqrt{2}) + (-1 \cdot 15x^2\cdot e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x})$$

That appears to be wrong, but I'm not sure why. What's the problem?

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $5x^3$ in the first term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first term of your sum you've forgotten the factor $5x^3$...
You rather have

> $$
> (-1\cdot e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x} \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \color{red}{5x^3}) + (-1 \cdot 15x^2\cdot e^{\sqrt{2}\cdot x})
> $$

Answer (score 1):

The derivstive of first **times the second**. You forgot the second, i.e. you forgot to multiply by $5x^3$